# Why is my command line copy not working?

Tags: scripting, find

I want to copy n1.sh to all folders in SerradoMel/MT10 directory
This is my solution

```
find . -type d -exec cp n1.sh /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT10{} \;
```

But there is no n1.sh in MT10 folders.Why?
If I try

```
find . -type d -exec echo cp n1.sh /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT11{} \;
```

I got

```
cp n1.sh /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT11.
```

But file has not been copied.My current pwd is

```
/home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT06/meas_2016-07-13_20-29-43
```

Comment: Two things catch my eye here: 1) you're probably lacking a `/` before your curly brackets; 2) `cp` won't copy directories without the `-r` flag. In general, I suggest doing a dry-run to see what's actually happening (e.g. using `echo <cmd>` - in your case: `find . -type d -exec echo cp n1.sh /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT10{} \;`)

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: And could you please tell us why you want the same script in all those directories? There might be better alternatives to copying it.

Comment: @mreithub Yes ,I want n1.sh to be copied to all folders,take a look at my edit please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
find /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT10 -type d -exec cp -v n1.sh {} \;
```

I added the "-v" so you can see the file being copied.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
find . -type d -exec cp /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT06/meas_2016-07-13_20-29-43/n1.sh {} \;
```

where

- `/home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT06/meas_2016-07-13_20-29-43/n1.sh` is absolute path of `n1.sh` file (check for correct path)
- no need to add a  `/home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT10{}`, find will replace `{}` by current dir.